# Hexedit libmmcamera2_isp_modules.so to fix camera daemon crash

Tags: camera, crashes

I'm trying to get the camera working for the LG G4 (msm8992) in Android 10 (for almost a year now.

Can someone help me hexediting the camera blob (system/vendor/lib/libmmcamera2_isp_modules.so).
This blob seems to be a common cause of camera crashes:
https://github.com/search?q=%22libmmcamera2_isp_modules.so%22&type=Commits

I dont know what to look for to modify in the blob. I would like some guidance on what to look for once hexediting and debugging to find why the lib is causing the camera to fail..

Here is my log of the crashes during the startup of the camera app: https://github.com/aoleary/g4_issues/blob/main/Camera%20startup%20error

And the two tombstones :
https://github.com/aoleary/g4_issues/blob/main/tombstone_00
https://github.com/aoleary/g4_issues/blob/main/tombstone_01

These are the device trees :
https://github.com/aoleary/device_lge_g4-common/commits/q_cam
https://github.com/Suicide-Squirrel/Titan-Kernel-LG-G4/tree/staging/android-10.0
https://github.com/Suicide-Squirrel/proprietary_vendor_lge/tree/android-10.0

Comment: Modifying a binary via hex editor is possible but very very complicated. The common way to reverse engineer a binary is to decompile it to assembler using a tool like Ghidra or IDA and then modify it. But this requires still a lot of knowledge and if you don't know exactly what is going wrong it is even more complicated. In any way for modifying binaries I would recommend to post your question on https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com